# Java - How to keep timer running when using nextInt()

Tags: java, timer

I have built a quiz which generates random maths questions. in my main method, I have got a while loop which uses the System.currentTimeMillis() method. inside the while loop I am using the nextInt() method from the Scanner object. This in part stops the timer from working. In short, I am trying to give the user 10 seconds to complete 10 simple maths questions. When the timer runs out I just want to system out the user's score. Please see the code for a better understanding of what I'm doing.

```
    int score = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    QuizGenerator qg = new QuizGenerator();
    ArrayList<Question> quiz = qg.generateQuiz();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //fetch starting time
    while(false||(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<10000) {
        for(Question q : quiz) {
            System.out.println(q.getQuestion());
            int playerAnswer = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("You scored: " + score);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop waiting for user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154207/how-to-stop-waiting-for-user-input)

Comment: `nextInt` is also a blocking operation so as long as the code is waiting for input it will not get to the last `System.out`. Other than that @assylias already pointed out your flaw in the while loop.

Comment: @thomasters You need two threads to achieve this - one will be blocking and waiting for user input, the other will be running the timer and will interrupt the first thread. Look around, there are plenty of questions like this on Stack Overflow, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059068/set-timeout-for-users-input

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak there are indeed other options than running it in a separate thread building on the way the most common consoles handle input buffering. Two threads are definitely a possibility but you don't **need** to use that way.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak shame on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this simply by using java.util.Timer. for example,

```
 public class QuizeRunner{

    int score = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    QuizGenerator qg = new QuizGenerator();
    ArrayList<Question> quiz = qg.generateQuiz();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //fetch starting time

    //timer
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule( new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if ( ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ) / 1000 > 10 )
            {
                System.out.println( "time out !!. score " + score );
                System.exit( 0 );
            }
        }

    }, 1000, 1000 );


    //ask questions
    for ( Question q : quiz )
    {

        System.out.println( q.getQuestion() );
        int playerAnswer = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println( "You scored: " + score );
 }
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Really appreciate your help :) Tried to plus 1 you but I'm too much of a noob.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nextInt() is blocking, so you want to call it only when you know there is a user input. Try this:

```
int qIndex = 0;
System.out.println(quiz.get(qIndex++).getQuestion());
while((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<10000) {
    if (System.in.available() > 0) {
         int playerAnswer = input.nextInt();
         // check answer..
         if(qIndex >= quiz.size()) break;
         System.out.println(quiz.get(qIndex++).getQuestion());
    }
    // Allow few milliseconds 
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```