# add timeout for blocking read() in process

Tags: java, timeout, blocking

I have a process which do read() that is blocking and I want to add timeout that interrupt the read operation.
this is what I tried to do but the timeout happened only after read is finished

```
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long theRealTimeOfProcess , endTime ,timeOutMillis;
        String line;
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            if (Objects.isNull(timeUnit) || Objects.isNull(timeout)) {
                return output.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            timeOutMillis = timeUnit.toMillis(timeout);
            while (true) {
                line = output.readLine();
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                theRealTimeOfProcess = endTime - startTime;
                if (timeOutMillis <= theRealTimeOfProcess) {
                    throw new ShellTaskExecutionException(String.format("Task reached timeout %s %s", timeout, timeUnit));
                }
                if (Objects.isNull(line)) {
                    break;
                }
                result.add(line);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't quite understand what's the problem .. how is blocking related to timeout? To make it not-blocking, do the reading in a background thread and cancel it on exceeding the timeout.

Comment: output.readLine() may take several min but i want to spot it if it pass certain time for example 30 sec , but because its blocking it always wait for it to complete

Comment: ahh .. I see, thanks for the clarification - though: why can a single line read take minutes? Broken connection, file disruption, ..?

Comment: What is the underlying i/o - socket?

Comment: no its process , i saw to socket solution but i cant use socket

Comment: did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72510274/terminate-a-stream-when-there-is-no-incoming-data-after-certain-timeout - maybe it has a grain of a solution for context also :)

Comment: @kleopatra for example if the user input sleep 100000 then its waiting for that time , my impl is for executing unix command