How to terminate Thread in Java If thread is waiting input?
I know Thread.stop() is deprecated and interrupt() or a way to use inner variable should be used.
However, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10962613/3809427 says "InputStream/OutputStream which are not interruptable" and I think thread waiting input can't be terminated by a way using inner variable. Following is an example.
Thread labelThread = Thread.ofVirtual().unstarted(() -> {
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
labelThread.start();
System.out.println("start");
Thread.sleep(3000);
labelThread.interrupt();
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(labelThread.isInterrupted());
System.out.println(labelThread.isAlive());

Output is following if you don't input any.
start
isInterrupted= true
isAlive= true

If you input any(e.g. 'a'), thread is terminated.
start
a
isInterrupted= true
isAlive= false

Actual process I want to terminate is inputReader() of external app and above is simplified code.
In these cases, stop() is only way to terminate thread? I can't completely understand following answer but stop() gives a negative impact on entire system, not only thread even if thread is as simple as above?
java - Thread.stop() - deprecated - Stack Overflow

Have you tried join ?

join() seems not to be related. I add join() as a trial but thread is continuing forever unless I input any(e.g. 'a').

"Actual process I want to terminate is inputReader() of external app and above is simplified code." -- where is there InputStream handling code in your "simplified" code? Why not instead post a decent [mre] simplified code, code that we can actually compile, run and modify?

Have you tried closing the stream?  I'm speculating I didn't test it but since read() throws IOException it might stop the reader and allow it to return.

You can have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10059356/1193808

@elfefe, t.join() does nothing to t. In fact, it really does nothing at all. t.join() does nothing. And, it continues to do nothing until thread t is finished, and then it returns.

The question boils down to, "can you interrupt/halt an in-progress System.in.read()?"  This is a good question, one to which I think the answer is in fact no.

@LouisWasserman > The question boils down to, "can you interrupt/halt an in-progress System.in.read()?"
Yes, and thank you for the clear answer, even which is negatively solved. I noticed another solution which doesn't close inputReader() . This may be XY problem as a result, but "there are cases which terminating threads is impossible" is useful information for others, too, I think. Thank you and sorry.
